# Styling Mail Chimp Form

Tags: css, forms, email, mailchimp

I have an email opt in form for Mail Chimp at the top of my site and I cannot get the size of it to change. I want the subscribe button to be on the same line as the email field. Am I doing something wrong?

This is my form code:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//gleefulthings.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0277df98c0e296a094149262c&amp;id=87ac16e6a6" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <input type="email" value="your email address" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">

<input type="text" name="b_0277df98c0e296a094149262c_87ac16e6a6" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>

    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
<!-- Defines how wide the opt-in will be and centers everything -->
#mc_embed_signup {
    width: 880px;
    margin: auto auto !important;
}

<!-- Moves the form to the left and sets the width -->
#mc_embed_signup input.email {
    float: left !important;
    width: 700px !important;
}

<!-- Defines the height of the div surrounding the form -->
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group {
    min-height: 20px !important;
}

<!-- Moves the button to the right, removes the rounded corners, pushes the button up 45px -->
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
    background: #bbcf14 !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-top: -45px;
}
```

Here's a link to my test site: http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/. Any help is much appreciated! I've been Googling and can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I'm not seeing any of that CSS on your example page, have you linked to your css file or are there any caches that need to be flushed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. That code is in the same CSS file I'm using for the rest of the site.

Comment: When I inspect the form, there's no css applied specifically to that form. Try removing your HTML comments (the <!-- --> stuff) and it looks like your final @media query isn't closed before the form CSS, which is also probably causing issue.

Comment: ok, I removed the comments but it didn't change anything. What do you mean @media query? I'm not sure what that is. :(

Comment: A media query is usually used to make CSS changes specific to a particular window size for responsive designs (see here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). You just need a closing curly bracket right after the closing bracket for the .sidebar .widget.enews-widget rule right above your form CSS (add on line 1540).

Comment: That appears to have been the problem! I must have deleted it by accident when I added the mail chimp CSS. Thank you SO much! I never would have figured that out without you! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"], .button
```

{

```
    background-color: #111;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 140px;
    float: right;
    height: 52px;
}

#mce-EMAIL
 {
    width: 89.9%;
    float: left;
}
```

Dear Friend, I am edit your website online as my inspect element Chrome tool, it work fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK74h.jpg) This is screen shot of afterward applying CSS into your website.

Still you have any problem feel free to contact me.